# searching number in body using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to search all numbers (of digits 8) in body using jQuery, its only returning first no. in body?

```
var myRe = /[0-9]{8}/;  
var myArray = myRe.exec($('body').html());  
alert(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `g` or 'global' flag to the regular expression. Now instead of using `exec()` which only returns the first match, call `match()` on the string itself, which returns an array of all results:

```
var myRe = /[0-9]{8}/g;
var myArray = $('body').html().match(myRe);
```

Comment: Did this resolve the problem? If so, please be sure to mark the answer "accepted", that way we both get some reputation.